# How to prove $E_{k+G}=E_{k}$ in solid state physics when T is degenerated using Bloch theorem?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, solid-state-physics, crystals

In several textbooks I read about solid state physics, the way to introduce the first Brillouin zone and the energy band structure is like the this:

**Step 1**: The Hamiltonian could be diagonalized by a set of eigen functions:$H|\psi_{n,k}>=E_{n,k}|\psi_{n,k}>$

**Step 2**: The Hamiltonian is invariant under the lattice translation T, thus $[\hat{T},H]=0$, where $\forall r. \hat{T}f(r)=f(r+a)$

**Step 3**: From the representation theorem of the Unitary group, we have $\hat{T}\psi_{n,k}(r)=\psi_{n,k}(r+a)=e^{ika}\psi_{n,k}(r)$

**Step4**: Since $\hat{T}\psi_{n,k+G}(r)=e^{i(k+G)a}\psi_{n,k+G}(r)=e^{ika}\psi_{n,k+G}(r)$,where $G$ is the reversal vector.Thus the $\psi_{n,k+G} $ and the $\psi_{n,k}(r)$ shares the same eigen value $e^{ika}$ under the operation of $\hat{T}$. Finally from Step 2, we claim that $\psi_{n,k}(r)=\psi_{n,k+G}(r)$, thus the energy $E_n(k+G)=E_n(k)$.

And I have trouble understanding the Step 4 for a few weeks, that, how we know that $\hat{T}$ is non-degenerated? If it is degenerated, how can we claim $\psi_{n,k}(r)=\psi_{n,k+G}(r)$ simply because they shares the same eigen value under $\hat{T}$？

Thanks